# Initialize char array to hold non-null-terminated string

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am trying to initialize a `char` array with a long string. However, I do not want it to be `NULL` terminated.

This:

```
const char s[] = "The actual string is much longer then this...";
```

is much easier to read (and to write) than this:

```
const char s[] = {'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'c', 't', 'u', 'a', 'l', ' ', 's', ...};
```

but the former gets `NULL` terminated. Is there a way to avoid the `NULL` on a string literal?

The reason for doing this is that there is the need to pack densely strings in memory of fixed size length known during development.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `NULL`-terminator?

Comment: We need a lot more information to give you a useful answer. For example, is this initialization only going to occur once in the program's lifetime? Is performance an issue? What's the outer problem?

Comment: It will actually be an array of strings, which I need to be packed tight into memory (no `NULL` between the strings) for various fast indexing purposes

Comment: How will the code that indexes the array know where the strings end?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They are all a fixed length, and all of equal length

Comment: Perhaps you should [generate them with `xxd`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176111/66358), then?

Comment: Please add this constraint into the question.

Comment: Aha! **Now** I can give you a useful answer. By the way, "NULL" is a pointer. You mean "nul".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**.

A string literal is a C-string which, by definition, is null-terminated.

Either ignore the final character, revisit your requirements (why do you care about a final character?!) or … I dunno, something else. Perhaps [generate the objects with `xxd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176111/66358)?

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
size_t length = 45;
char s[] = "The actual string is much longer then this..";
s[length - 1] = ".";
```

See what you have there has a trade-off between readability and functionality and I think that you can get away easily with this, since you can **not** avoid the NULL terminating string in the "normal" initialization.

---

If I were in your shoes, I would re-consider my approach and use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: What is `length`? If you're going to do a `strlen`, that's an `O(n)` operation. An `O(n)` operation for initialization? This looks heavy.

Comment: That rings me a bell @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but if he wants to do that kind of stuff, he better know the length and hard-code it. Otherwise, use a NULL-terminating string.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The requirement itself is suspect.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you have some reason to think performance matters here? This is just initialization. Also, the `strlen` could be optimized out here. Your complaint sounds like premature optimization -- the worst excuse to make a design more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Lightness said that because I was worried about it, but we deleted the comments. :)

Comment: If he deletes the one above, I'll delete my one above and this one. Otherwise, I'm going to keep my comment there to clarify that being concerned about performance here requires a justification and we don't have one.

Comment: Well @DavidSchwartz the fault here is mine, not one of Lightness. There was a question which used `memcpy()` and I posted a similar comment. So Now Lightness just makes fun of me, but in a good+fair way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I was mostly joking, in response to gsamaras's equivalent comment on another answer. Copy/pasting his conclusion on said issue was the biggest clue :P

Comment: OP was using `const char[]`

Comment: @Amadeus it's the functionality trade-off I mentioned in my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want essy to write code, copy to a second array but miss off the last char. You can use a char pointer in the first case to perhaps save some memory

Answer (score 0):

The terminating nul will be omitted if it doesn't fit. Since your strings are all fixed length, that's not a problem to arrange. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char foo[3][4] = { "four", ".by." , "3333" };

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
             putchar(foo[i][j]);
         putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to compile this I get `error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long`

Comment: Weird. Compiling as C++, I get this too.

Comment: http://ideone.com/9Wzzgb

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a string literal not null terminated.

But you actually want to pack a number of strings densely and you know both the sizes and the strings at development time.

Assume:

> "First"
>
> "Second"
>
> "Third"

to pack them you can safely do:

```
char const s[] = "First""Second""Third";
```

You only need to save lengths and properly reconstruct termination in case you want to print or use std string. That is easy though.

As a bonus you have saved from the excess pointer you would have to store for each and everyone string needed.